# Cutting Raster using two Polygons as Masks

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, masking

I am trying to cut this raster in order to drop the outside of the walls white area and the area with the dots.
I made one step using as mask the  green polygon but i couldn't remove the inside of the walls area with the dots.
Any idea?
 [image: andros]

Comment: Have you tried running a second clipping with a polygon of the inside?

Comment: Yes, it keeps only the inside the polygon area. I want to keep only the walls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works this way:

1. Create a clip polygon for the outer border
2. Create a clip poygon for the inner border
3. Create a multipolygon with the second layer as a hole using `Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Difference`
4. Clip the Raster to that multipolygon using `Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper`

Comment: This is working perfectly.